# Rearranging Table in R using tidyverse

Tags: r, pivot-table, tidyverse

I have data formatted in the following way:

```
-------------------------
| A01 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A01 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A01 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A02 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A02 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A02 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A03 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A03 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A03 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A04 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A04 | value |          |
-------------------------
| A04 | value |          |
```

I want to extract the values from rows labeled as A02 and paste them in separate column beside the rows labeled as A01. Similarly for, A03 and A04 and so on.

Basically I want to rearrange like this:

```
-------------------------
| A01 | value | A02 | value |
 -------------------------
| A01 | value | A02 | value |
 -------------------------
| A01 | value | A02 | value |
 -------------------------
| A03 | value | A04 | value |
 -------------------------
| A03 | value | A04 | value |
 -------------------------
| A03 | value | A04 | value |
```

I am learning the tidyverse in R, but I am very new and I have not been able to find the right function to do this yet. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can look for all rows labeled with an even number or odd numbers, separate them and join them together afterwards. In this approach it is assumed, that labels only go to maximum **A09** (if larger values are present, you have to modify **substr**). Also it will only work if you have the same amount of even and odd labelled values. But for your example data it works as requested!

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  

## example data ##                 
value = c(rep(1:4,3))    
who = paste0("A0", c(rep(1:4,3))  )

tbl <- tibble::tibble(who = who,  value = value)

## substr(who,3,3) extracts last letter from name, as.numeric() turns it into numeric
## %% 2 == 0 <- modulo division, return remainder, only even numbers have remainder 0

tbl <- tbl %>% mutate(is_even = as.numeric(substr(who,3,3)) %%  2 == 0) 

## Filter all rows with even number in label
tbl_even <- tbl %>% filter(is_even == TRUE) %>% dplyr::select(-is_even)

## Filter all rows with odd number in label
tbl_odd <- tbl %>% filter(is_even == FALSE) %>% dplyr::select(-is_even)


## Join even and odd values together
result <- tbl_odd %>% cbind(tbl_even)
```